# how to add a field to models

Tags: django, django-views

I have a question of how to inherit a field from the model and display it in the admin panel (and manage it).

I am using [django-avatar](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar) app.

Also i have a profile model(not relevant to django-avatar):

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

How can I add an avatar field to the profile model so that in the admin panel in the user's 'profile' section, I can see the avatar for this user?

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: To do exactly that you need to create a [custom user model](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatar/")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourpath import Profile

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Comment: does this link the current user avatars from the application (django-avatar)?